# PHP - how to check matched words from a string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

How to match? Expected valid input:

`email-sms-call` or 
  `sms,email,call` or 
  `sms email call` or
  `smsemailcall`

Which only match when there is space in-between

```
<?php
function contains($needles, $haystack) {
  return count(
          array_intersect(
                  $needles, 
                  explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $haystack))
            )
          );
}

$database_column_value = 'email,sms,call';
$find_array = array('sms', 'email');
$found_array_times = contains($find_array, $database_column_value);

if($found_array_times) {
  echo "Found times: {$found_array_times}";
}
else {
  echo "not found";
}


?>
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to use strpos?

Comment: Pattern words can be unordered?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `preg_split` function:

```
function contains($needles, $haystack) {
  if (!$needles || !$haystack) 
      return false;

  $result = array_intersect($needles, preg_split("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]+/", $haystack));  
  return count($result);
}

$database_column_value = 'email,sms,call';
$find_array = ['sms', 'email', 'phone'];
$found_array_times = contains($find_array, $database_column_value);

if ($found_array_times) {
    echo "Found times: {$found_array_times}";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

The output:

```
Found times: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function contains_word($word, $text)
{
    return null!==strpos($word,$text);
}
function count_keyWords($keyWords, $input) {
    $numKeyWords=0;
    foreach ($keyWords as $word) {
        if(contains_word($word, $input)) {
            $numKeyWords++;
        }
    }
    return $numKeyWords;
}


//Usage
$input="sms,email,call";
$keyWords=['sms', 'email', 'call'];
$numKeywords=count_keyWords($keyWords, $input);
echo $numKeywords." found";
```